# Django LogoutView doesn't logout but redirects to login page

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-sessions, django-login

I am new to Django. I have this problem that The auth LoginView works perfectly well but the LogoutView doesnt.

It only redirects to login page.

```
 from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views  
  
    path('user/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
    path('user/logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='logout.html'), name='logout'),
```

My logout.html file is as follows

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %} {% load static %}
{% block content %}
<br />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-7 mx-auto">
      <div class="card card-signin my-5">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-center"><b>Register</b></h5>
          <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
              <br />
              {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button
                class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase"
                type="submit"
              >
                Sign Up</button
              ><br /><br />
            </div>
            <small
              ><p class="text-center">
                Already Registered!
                <a href="{% url 'login' %}"><b>Login Now!</b></a>
              </p></small
            >
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Please does anyone know why this could be happening. Is it possible that the default auth LoginView could be working and the default auth Logoutview is not working. Or am I doing something wrong?.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Why are you sure that it is just redirecting to the login page and not that it is logging the user out _and_ redirecting to the login page?

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is because I still have access to all the pages with @login_required. Profile page is still active and Logout still shows at my nav-bar

Comment: Actually i wonder why you are using login form in the logout template?!

Comment: Thank you @SerioUs. actually that was the genesis of my problem. The log in and log out templates were the same. I also had login template at href of my logout button , so what happens is that when I click logout, it just loads the login page without sending the logout request.  I have now changed the template and it is working now. Thank you :)  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send your html detail of logout view.
you are doing it right but may be you are not giving instructions to your logout view.

Comment: Thank you for your response- I have  just edited my initial question to include the Html file